# dotnet 6 + typeloadexception when running dotnet test... but the tests pass and run in Rider/VS just fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, xunit, .net-6.0

I have a dotnet 6 project that looks like this:

- MyProject.API
- MyProject.Tests
- MyProject.Shared

I have about 41 tests, using xUnit/Moq, and they all pass when I run them in Rider (and VS).

I was configuring an azure pipelines build, which failed with this:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' threw an exception.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Registry is not supported on this platform.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKeyCore(RegistryHive hKey, RegistryView view)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Registry..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetBaseKeyFromKeyName(String keyName, String& subKeyName)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(String keyName, String valueName, Object defaultValue)
   at NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.RegistryBase.Exist(String property)
   at NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.NUnitTestAdapter..ctor()
Exception System.TypeLoadException, Exception thrown executing tests

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    41, Skipped:     0, Total:    41, Duration: 3 s
```

- On my dev machine (MacBookPro 2020): I get the message as shown
- In azure pipelines, using the ubuntu-latest image: I get the message as shown
- In azure pipelines, using the windows-2022 image: I get the TypeLoadException but not the TypeInitializationException (presumably because there's a registry in that image).

Some things that don't make sense to me:

- I'm not using NUnit, but it's the NUnitTestAdapter that throws an exception

  - I tried adding/removing it specifically to ensure that the NUnit3TestAdapter was not present, with no change.
- Everything is configured for AnyCPU but to be sure I tried forcing the tests to run with /p:TargetPlatform=x64 (and x86), with no change.

Comment: Did you try `windows-2019`?

Comment: any luck on this error?